# How to manually call another target from a make target?

Tags: gnu-make

I would like to have a makefile like this:

```
cudaLib :
    # Create shared library with nvcc

ocelotLib :
    # Create shared library for gpuocelot

build-cuda : cudaLib
    make build

build-ocelot : ocelotLib
    make build

build :
    # build and link with the shared library
```

I.e. the `*Lib` tasks create a library that runs cuda directly on the device, or on gpuocelot respectively.

For both build tasks I need to run the same build steps, only creating the library differs.

Is there an alternative to running make directly?

```
make build
```

Kind of a post-requisite?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have written it, the `build` target will need to do something different depending on whether you have just done an ocelot or cuda build. That's another way of saying you have to parameterise `build` in some way. I suggest separate build targets (much like you already have), with associated variables. Something like:

```
build-cuda: cudaLib
build-ocelot: ocelotLib

build-cuda build-ocelot:
    shell commands
    which invoke ${opts-$@}
```

On the command-line you type `make build-cuda` (say). Make first builds `cudaLib`, then it carries out the recipe for `build-cuda`. It expands the macros before calling the shell. `$@` in this case is `build-cuda`, thus `${opts-$@}` is first expanded to `${opts-build-cuda}`. Make now goes on to expand `${opts-build-cuda}`. You will have defined `opts-build-cuda` (and of course its sister `opts-build-ocelot`) elsewhere in the makefile.

P.S. Since `build-cuda` et. al. are not real files, you had better tell make this (`.PHONY: build-cuda`).

Comment: How would I invoke opts-build-cuda? With «make opts-build-cuda», or «make ${opts-$@}» in this case?

Comment: You invoke _build_cuda_ (`make build_cuda`). Make will dutifully carry out the shell commands first for `cudaLib`, then the shell commands for `build-cuda`. In the process of generating this final set of commands make has to expand the variable `opts-build-cuda`. (Presumably you could have other variables, like `deptool-build-cuda` or `build-cuda-output-dir` etc. etc.)

This allows you to write one block of commands in the Makefile that look quite different when they are passed to the shell.

P.S. Always invoke make with `--warn-undefined-variable`, it will save you much heartache.

Answer (score 88):

<sup>Note: This answer focuses on the aspect of a robust recursive invocation of a different target in a given makefile.</sup>

To complement [Jack Kelly's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5382209/45375), here's a GNU makefile snippet that demonstrates the use of `$(MAKE)` to *robustly* invoke a different target in the same makefile (ensuring that the same `make` binary is called, and that the same makefile is targeted):

```sh
# Determine this makefile's path.
# Be sure to place this BEFORE `include` directives, if any.
THIS_FILE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

target:
    @echo $@  # print target name
    @$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_FILE) other-target # invoke other target

other-target:
    @echo $@ # print target name
```

Output:

```
$ make target

target
other-target
```

Using `$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))` and `-f ...` ensures that the `$(MAKE)` command uses the same makefile, even if that makefile was passed with an explicit path (`-f ...`) when make was originally invoked.

---

Note: While GNU `make` does have features for recursive invocations - for instance, variable `$(MAKE)` specifically exists to enable them - their focus is on invoking *subordinate* makefiles, not on calling a different target in the *same* makefile.

That said, even though the workaround above is somewhat cumbersome and obscure, it does use regular features and should be *robust*.

Here is the link to the manual section covering recursive invocations ("sub-makes"):

- [Recursive Use of make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable)

Comment: Just a comment on style. Wherever possible, please eschew calling _make_ from _make_. Sure, it's sometimes helpful, but when you have a choice don't do it. Your life will be better for it.  http://www.real-linux.org.uk/recursivemake.pdf

Answer (score 39):

Most versions of make set a variable `$(MAKE)` that you can use for recursive invocations.